# How to plot area between a predefined upper and lower bounds in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Data:

[Morocco_ObsClim](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m9jll48mfy328sg/Morocco_ObservedClim.csv)

[Morocco_ProjClim](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e27q1803l6xqq6e/Morocco_ProjectedClim.csv)

Code:

```
Morocco_ObservedClim <- read.csv(file = "Morocco_ObservedClim.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.string="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
Morocco_ProjectedClim <- read.csv(file = "Morocco_ProjectedClim.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.string="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)

# Select the data

obs_annualanom.df <- subset(Morocco_ObservedClim, DataSource %in% c("avg") & DataFormat %in% c("anom") & Timeframe %in% c("annual"))
obs_annualanom.df <- obs_annualanom.df[1:41,]
proj_annualanom.df <- subset(Morocco_ProjectedClim, gcm %in% c("avg","min","max") & DataFormat %in% c("anom") & Timeframe %in% c("annual"))

# Melting the data

obs_annualanom.df <- melt(obs_annualanom.df, id.vars=c("Year","DataSource","DataFormat","Timeframe"))
proj_annualanom.df <- melt(proj_annualanom.df, id.vars=c("Year","sres","gcm","DataFormat","Timeframe"))

# Plots

precip <- ggplot(data=obs_annualanom.df) + geom_line(aes(Year,value),subset=.(variable %in% c("Precip")),size=1.1)
precip <- precip + geom_line(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),colour="brown",size=1.1,subset=.(variable %in% c("Precip") & gcm %in% c("avg") & sres %in% c("20thC")))
precip <- precip + geom_area(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),fill="tan1",alpha=0.5,subset=.(variable %in% c("Precip") & gcm %in% c("max") & sres %in% c("20thC")))
precip <- precip + geom_area(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),fill="tan1",alpha=0.5,subset=.(variable %in% c("Precip") & gcm %in% c("min") & sres %in% c("20thC")))
precip <- precip + geom_line(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),colour="red",size=1.1,subset=.(variable %in% c("Precip") & gcm %in% c("avg") & sres %in% c("A2")))
precip <- precip + geom_area(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),fill="red3",alpha=0.3,subset=.(variable %in% c("Precip") & gcm %in% c("max") & sres %in% c("A2")))
precip <- precip + geom_area(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),fill="red3",alpha=0.3,subset=.(variable %in% c("Precip") & gcm %in% c("min") & sres %in% c("A2")))
precip <- precip + geom_line(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),colour="blue",size=1.1,subset=.(variable %in% c("Precip") & gcm %in% c("avg") & sres %in% c("A1B")))
precip <- precip + geom_area(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),fill="royalblue3",alpha=0.3,subset=.(variable %in% c("Precip") & gcm %in% c("max") & sres %in% c("A1B")))
precip <- precip + geom_area(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),fill="royalblue3",alpha=0.3,subset=.(variable %in% c("Precip") & gcm %in% c("min") & sres %in% c("A1B")))
precip <- precip + geom_line(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),colour="green4",size=1.1,subset=.(variable %in% c("Precip") & gcm %in% c("avg") & sres %in% c("B1")))
precip <- precip + geom_area(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),fill="palegreen3",alpha=0.3,subset=.(variable %in% c("Precip") & gcm %in% c("max") & sres %in% c("B1")))
precip <- precip + geom_area(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),fill="palegreen3",alpha=0.3,subset=.(variable %in% c("Precip") & gcm %in% c("min") & sres %in% c("B1")))
precip <- precip + labs(title="Precipitation",y="Anomalies (mm/year)", x="") + theme_bw() 
#precip <- precip + scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq(by=20)) #+ scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-50, 80, by=25))
precip <- precip + theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold", size=rel(2), hjust=0.5, vjust=1.5),
                     axis.text.x=element_text(color="black", size=rel(2.5), hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5),
                     axis.text.y=element_text(color="black", size=rel(2.5), hjust=1),
                     axis.title=element_text(face="bold", color="black", size=rel(1.7), hjust=0.5, vjust=0.2))

temp <- ggplot(data=obs_annualanom.df) + geom_line(aes(Year,value),subset=.(variable %in% c("Temp")),size=1.1)
temp <- temp + geom_line(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),colour="brown",size=1.1,subset=.(variable %in% c("Temp") & gcm %in% c("avg") & sres %in% c("20thC")))
temp <- temp + geom_area(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),fill="tan1",alpha=0.5,subset=.(variable %in% c("Temp") & gcm %in% c("max") & sres %in% c("20thC")))
temp <- temp + geom_area(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),fill="tan1",alpha=0.5,subset=.(variable %in% c("Temp") & gcm %in% c("min") & sres %in% c("20thC")))
temp <- temp + geom_line(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),colour="red",size=1.1,subset=.(variable %in% c("Temp") & gcm %in% c("avg") & sres %in% c("A2")))
temp <- temp + geom_area(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),fill="red3",alpha=0.3,subset=.(variable %in% c("Temp") & gcm %in% c("max") & sres %in% c("A2")))
temp <- temp + geom_area(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),fill="red3",alpha=0.3,subset=.(variable %in% c("Temp") & gcm %in% c("min") & sres %in% c("A2")))
temp <- temp + geom_line(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),colour="blue",size=1.1,subset=.(variable %in% c("Temp") & gcm %in% c("avg") & sres %in% c("A1B")))
temp <- temp + geom_area(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),fill="royalblue3",alpha=0.3,subset=.(variable %in% c("Temp") & gcm %in% c("max") & sres %in% c("A1B")))
temp <- temp + geom_area(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),fill="royalblue3",alpha=0.3,subset=.(variable %in% c("Temp") & gcm %in% c("min") & sres %in% c("A1B")))
temp <- temp + geom_line(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),colour="green4",size=1.1,subset=.(variable %in% c("Temp") & gcm %in% c("avg") & sres %in% c("B1")))
temp <- temp + geom_area(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),fill="palegreen3",alpha=0.3,subset=.(variable %in% c("Temp") & gcm %in% c("max") & sres %in% c("B1")))
temp <- temp + geom_area(data=proj_annualanom.df, aes(Year,value),fill="palegreen3",alpha=0.3,subset=.(variable %in% c("Temp") & gcm %in% c("min") & sres %in% c("B1")))
temp <- temp + labs(title="Temperature",y="Anomalies (degree C)", x="") + theme_bw()
#temp <- temp + scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq(by=20)) #+ scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-50, 80, by=25))
temp <- temp + theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold", size=rel(2), hjust=0.5, vjust=1.5),
                 axis.text.x=element_text(color="black", size=rel(2.5), hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5),
                 axis.text.y=element_text(color="black", size=rel(2.5), hjust=1),
                 axis.title=element_text(face="bold", color="black", size=rel(1.7), hjust=0.5, vjust=0.2))
```

My Results:

[image: Morocco_Precip]

[image: Morocco_Temp]

My objective: Reproduce this graph

[image: MyObjective]

Graphs nomenclature:

Solid lines represent the average.

The filled area is supposed to represent the max and min, which is available in the data.

The problem I have is that I want to achieve the following:
First, plot the averages which is accomplished successfully as per my resulting graphs.
Second, be able to set the fill between the min and max values in the data, which is where I fail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things.  Consider:

```
df <- subset(
  Morocco_ProjectedClim, 
  DataFormat=="anom" & gcm %in% c("avg", "min", "max") & Timeframe=="annual",
  select=c("sres", "Year", "gcm", "Temp")
)
df.cast <- dcast(df, sres + Year ~ gcm)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df.cast, aes(x=Year, y=avg)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=min, ymax=max, fill=sres), alpha=0.4) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=sres)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("tan1", "red3", "royalblue3", "palegreen3")) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("brown", "red", "blue", "green4"))
```

[image]

This does just the temperatures from the projected data set, but should give you a good idea on how to tackle the problem.

---

EDIT: this adds actuals:

```
ggplot(df.cast, aes(x=Year, y=avg)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=min, ymax=max, fill=sres), alpha=0.4) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=sres)) +
  geom_line(
    data=subset(Morocco_ObservedClim, DataSource == "avg" & DataFormat == "anom" & Timeframe == "annual"),
    aes(x=Year, y=Temp, color="Actual")
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("tan1", "red3", "royalblue3", "palegreen3")) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c(`20thC`="brown", A1B="red", A2="blue", B1="green4", Actual="black"))
```

Though note I didn't update the plot.

Comment: Beat me to it. I was going to include the use of both data sets, so my version started with just `ggplot() + ...` and then a single `geom_line()` with the "observed" data set, and then basically what you did.

Comment: @joran, feel free to post your version; you went the extra mile so might as well.

Comment: @joran, please post your version too.

Comment: @BrodieG, thanks for the clean and clear answer. I have one more thing to ask, so in your plot, the black curve from my plots is missing. That curve actually represents the actual observed data, whereas the brown one represent the model-simulated historical record. So ideally, I'd want to keep there as well.