# Specifying the color of confidence interval bands in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I am using the following `ggplot` command to plot a graph showing the variation of the mean of a certain variable (`aud.pc.mn`) over time. The color of the line is give by the variable region.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = mon.in.yr, y = aud.pc.mn, color = region)) +
      geom_line(size = 1) +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:12,1)) +
      facet_grid(. ~ avg.sh.aud.by.reg.month$year)
```

However, now I want to add confidence interval ribbons around each line but I want these bands to be a slightly lighter shade than the line, so that the line is also visible. For instance, if the line is red, I want the confidence band to be in pink.

If I add `fill = region` in the call to `geom_ribbon()`, like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = mon.in.yr, y = aud.pc.mn, color = region)) +
         geom_line(size = 1) + 
         geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = df$CI.lower, ymax = df$CI.upper, fill = region)) +
         scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:12,1)) + 
         facet_grid(. ~ avg.sh.aud.by.reg.month$year)
```

I get bands with the exact same color as the lines like this (and it looks really ugly):
[image]

How may I get the bands to be of a different shade than the lines?

Comment: Try `geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = CI.lower, ymax = CI.upper, fill = region), alpha=.2)`  to make them slightly transparent

Comment: Use `alpha` to add transparency to the ribbons.  The value should be between 0 and 1, where 1 is totally opaque.

Comment: thanks @MrFlick. Is there anyone I can remove the edges of the bands from becoming the color of the line itself?

Comment: You can move the `aes(color=)` from the `ggplot()` call to the `geom_line()` since you don’t want it to affect the ribbon.

Comment: @MrFlick it tells me `Error: Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?`

Comment: What exactly did you try? Sounds like you just didn't move the color aesthetic correctly. It's a lot easier to help when you provide a reproducible example with input data that we can run and test with ourselves.

Comment: This could be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861617/how-to-plot-area-between-a-predefined-upper-and-lower-bounds-in-ggplot2